# How to specify DNS on iOS when connected via VPN?

Tags: ios, vpn, dns

I have set up a VPN connection using my FritzBox 6330. This works great on my Macbook Air if I specify a DNS server (192.168.178.1 - which is the address of my FritzBox) in the network settings of the VPN.

On iOS however there is no such entry field, hence no names can  be resolved. The VPN itself works. I can connect to various IP addresses.

Comment: iOS 7x I presume?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The DNS settings over a VPN connection should be forced by the VPN server. This makes sure DNS queries get routed securely over the VPN, and allows you to see private services on the intranet that may not be exposed as public DNS records.

It's possible the VPN server may not be telling iOS what DNS server to use, something that could be solved by a configuration change in the VPN server?

Comment: This indeed is true and the solution was simple: I rebooted the FritzBox and now it works.

Comment: This might work, but the explanation is wrong - VPN routes traffic, and that will include DNS normally too, so all DNS will always be secure.  The problem is that most DNS will not answer queries from unknown IPs, so you need to change the DNS you use when you change the IP you're using as well.

Comment: Rebooting the Fritzbox fixed the same problem for me!

Answer (score 2):

When using IKEv2, iOS ignores pushed DNS settings when split-include tunnelling is used.

Comment: So how do we include VPN dns server to use by the system in case of split tunnel with match domains?

Comment: @iSpark IIRC, you can specify it in .mobileconfig files. It allows a lot more control, and I think it is possible within the rule cascade https://developer.apple.com/business/documentation/Configuration-Profile-Reference.pdf

Comment: I see DNS resolution issue on iOS14 and macOS11 with spilt VPN, do you see any issue there?

Comment: @iSpark I don't think this is new to iOS14. Both Apple macOS and iOS won't use the pushed DNS server setting with split-includes. But I think this can be avoided using .mobileconfig configuration (not tested myself yet, until I get another issue dealt with).

Answer (score 0):

See complete Answer [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/52878/46541):

> The Wi-Fi settings are easy to override using the device itself, but
>   it's not global but instead an override on a per-network name basis.
>   Go to the network settings for a specific Wi-Fi. Under the detailed
>   screen (tap the blue > sign once you are connected) and swipe up to
>   expose the DHCP / BootP / Static IP address part of the screen. You
>   can tap to edit DNS and append, delete or substitute your choice of
>   DNS settings from that screen.
>
> When I need to run a custom DNS, I often use VPN to get to a router
>   with known settings and this works over Wi-Fi and cellular data since
>   all traffic goes to the VPN where I can control the DNS. This requires
>   time and a server (Amazon web service free tier is ideal for low cost
>   hosting).

Source: [bmike](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/5472/bmike)