# DNS Setup on a Per-SSID basis?

Tags: ios, dns, apple-configurator

I manage a number of iOS devices. These devices are supervised via Apple Configurator. When they connect to a specific SSID, I want the devices to use the servers specified by DHCP (If needed, I can explicitly set the DNS as well.) However, when connected to any other network, I would like for these devices to use OpenDNS.

Is there a way to:

1. Set the default DNS Servers for a device, even for new wifi connections?
2. Override that default DNS Address?
3. Ideally, configurable through a profile so the user cannot change this?

I know that what I'm asking for [isn't possible on cellular networks](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/52875/how-can-i-change-the-cellular-dns-server-on-ios) but I'm hoping it is for wifi. I have looked at solutions like [DNS Override](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/dns-override/id1060830093?mt=8) and I'm fine with a paid solution, but that app requires users to manually change the DNS configuration. It gives a default, but no way to specify it on a per-SSID basis. (Additionally, it wants to create a VPN connection over cellular, and I don't want that.)

Comment: Generally speaking the WiFi (and cellular) network specifies parameters like DNS, gateway and netmask. DNS Override is an interesting app, you may want to check with the developers to see if you can configure their app via Apple Configurator or other means. Note that AskDifferent works best when you limit your posts to**one** question per post. Doing otherwise may lead to your post being removed.

Comment: Yes, while the network CAN specify DNS, I want to overwrite that, which is possible for a user to manually do. And I understand the one question per post, it isn’t really multiple questions, I’m looking for a solution that meets all three criteria (#3 is ideal, but not required.)